# Display complete object from camera with specific rotation in unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have different kind of objects with variable dimensions and placed at different position in a scene. I want to focus/display each object with the camera with a hard code rotation (north rotation). Like with specific camera rotation I want to focus the object that it completely show to the camera and center of the screen. For this reason, I have write this code snippet that
1

1. Get the position behind the specific focus object using
   `TransformPoint`
2. Provide the elevation using the largest `extent` of the `bound` so that it display maximum area of the object.
3. Assign the `position` and the fixed `rotation`

   ```
    Vector3 dest = destination.transform.TransformPoint(0, 0, behindPositionDistance);// GetBehindPosition(destination.transform, behindPositionDistance, elevation);
    Debug.Log(dest);
    float eleveMax = Mathf.Max(destination.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().bounds.extents.x, destination.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().bounds.extents.z);
    dest = new Vector3(dest.x, eleveMax, dest.z);
    camera.transform.position = dest;
    camera.transform.rotation = lookNorth;
   ```

But the problem is, it is not accurately working with all objects as every object is at different position and dimension. I want to focus the full object using the camera but without changing the rotation.

Comment: You could just raytrace an intersection with the object at the outer limits of the cameras fov. if there is no intersection, the object is completely visible. I think this would be a way more safe way of achieving your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe create an empty gameobject as a child of your objects. Use that as your Camera position at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use an orthographic camera, you can set the camera's `orthographicSize` dynamically based on the `size` of the `bounds` of the GameObject. This is probably the easiest solution.

If you need a perspective camera, you can get the `Plane`s or corners of the camera frustum via `GeometryUtility.CalculateFrustumPlanes(Camera.main)` or `Camera.CalculateFrustumCorners` and use the results from either to manually test that your `Bounds` is entirely inside.

With a perspective camera, you could also compute the necessary distance from the object based on the size of the object's bounds and the FOV of the camera. If I'm not mistaken, this would be something along the lines of `distance = 0.5 * size / tan(0.5 * fov)`, but the function doesn't have to be precise; it just needs to work for your camera. Alternatively, you could keep distance constant and compute FOV from the size of the object, although I wouldn't recommend that because frequent FOV changes sound disorienting for the viewer; my point is that there are many options.